# highcharts polar chart with gradient color fills

Tags: highcharts

I've followed the HighChart example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-gradient/) for the gradient color fill on a pie chart, but I'm having issues getting the gradient fill to work on a polar chart. See my [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ou4wvLwz/13/)

Issue #1: On the first chart the gradient is happening on each individual wedge, instead of the center of the whole polar chart.

Issue #2: On the second chart, if I define the colors for each wedge, I don't get any gradient fill.

```
data: [
    {y: 1, color: 'red'},
    {y: 2, color: 'blue'},
    {y: 3, color: 'orange'},
    {y: 4, color: 'green'},
    {y: 5, color: 'gray'},
    {y: 4, color: 'brown'}
]
```

How can I get the gradient fill to work from the center of the chart and have different colors for each wedge?

Answer (score 0):

For first issue -> Use [LINEAR GRADIENTS](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors) as it is one type of column charts.

For second issue -> If you define color in data series it is unknown by highcharts. In you function where you define Radialize the colors

```
Highcharts.getOptions().colors
```

here default  colors of highcharts is used . If you want to use custom colors you have to update highcharts default colors first.

For demonstration purpose I have updated `plotOptions` of second chart

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval: 60
        },
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            colorByPoint: true //added this
        }
    },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvo0fL8h/) demo

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Deep 3015, but the Linear Gradient still isn't correct. It's going from light to dark from left to right on each wedge. I'm trying to go from light to dark from the center of the chart to the perimeter of each wedge. [Example](https://ibb.co/jyg0J7)

Comment: Ok I will have to define custom gradient for that purpose. I will update once I make it proper

Comment: Hi, check this http://jsfiddle.net/q1k13wLb/ column without type polar. I think like this you want. But when it is updated with type polar It result different from what you expect